# aliasing a slightly complex script on Linux/bash

Tags: bash, alias

Stormvirux provided this nice script in another thread.  It puts column headings on the output of an `ls -l` listing:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ echo Permissions links Owner Group Size Last_modMonth Last_modTime Last_modTime Filename; ls -l ; } | column -t | awk 'NR!~/^(2)$/'
ls -l | head -1
```

Just running it on the command line works great.  I like it and want to use it as an alias for, say `lsl` on a Linux system running bash.

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to make the delimiters work so it is interpreted correctly.  When I try just using the alias command on the command line (which I do before I commit it to a configuration file like `.bashrc`), it won't work.  I get various errors when I try various ways to package it so it's interpreted correctly.

Can someone tell me how to get this working as an alias, or point me to a good reference that can clearly tell me what I need to do to get something like this working as an alias?

Comment: This is not at all similar to the proposed duplicate, which is about multiple-word alias *names*.

Comment: ... and further, the top answer is about a git-specific method of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, you can define it as a function in your `.bashrc`:

```
lsl() {
  { echo Permissions links Owner Group Size Last_modMonth Last_modTime Last_modTime Filename;
  ls -l; } | 
  column -t | 
  awk 'NR!~/^(2)$/'
  ls -l | head -1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you must do it as an alias:

```
alias lsl='{ echo Permissions links Owner Group Size Last_modMonth Last_modTime Last_modTime Filename; ls -l ; } | column -t | awk '\''NR!~/^(2)$/'\'';ls -l | head -1'
```

We need to escape the internal single quotes with backslashes so they aren't interpreted as stopping the string.

If we use double quotes instead then the `!` is interpreted as a [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators) and needs even more escaping, which is probably the most confusing problem you ended up with (something like "`bash: !~/^: event not found`", which is incomprehensible gibberish).

---

The above will work, but better would just be to put that file somewhere in your path and make it executable. Create, say, `~/.local/bin` and a script `lsl` with exactly the contents of your post inside there, then `chmod +x ~/.local/bin/lsl` and add a line to your `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

to make sure that executables in that directory will be found. Then you can just write `lsl` anywhere to run the code. This approach is more maintainable and easier to understand.